# C#10 unclear CS8600 warning

Tags: c#, blazor, c#-10.0

I'm currently migrating a Blazor project to .NET6 which comes with C# 10.
With the new language version I'm getting a warning with the following code:

```
if (tmp is null)
    oldValue = "";
else
    oldValue = tmp.ToString();
```

The warning is: CS8600 "Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type".
`tmp` is of type `object?`. That is the reason why I'm checking if it is null in the if clause.
I have noticed that many warnings of this type occur.

So what is the reason behind that? The Help page does not contain any information yet. (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/sorry-we-don-t-have-specifics-on-this-csharp-error?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8600)))

Comment: `object.ToString` have `string?` return type. Try `oldValue = tmp?.ToString() ?? ""`

Comment: And for an exciting discussion about why `object.ToString()` is annotated as returning `string?` rather than `string`, see here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466

Comment: @Satpal `is` always checks against `null` while `==` *may* call overloaded operator

Comment: @UnusualWays Does your IDE suggest any automatic refactoring? In Visual Studio, you might be able to click on a light bulb and let the IDE fix the issue.

Comment: @JL0PD Although `ToString()` has the return type `string?`, I think by convention it should never return null, therefore it's likely safe to just do `oldValue = tmp.ToString()!`.

Comment: @PMF, "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not.". Even though by convention there's can't be null, actually it can be and this will shoot your legs off sooner or later

Comment: @JL0PD - you can make that 1st comment an answer.

Comment: I am not as interested in how to manage the warning as much as I am interested in why this is a warning.  Why is is a bad thing to set objects' values to null?

Answer (score 8):

It appears that CS8600 warning is thrown when the compiler is not sure if the type is nullable or not.  If you cast oldValue = (string?) tmp; the compiler is happy and the warning goes away.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *Coalesce* operator (edited with @Alex Kalabukhov correction):

```
string oldValue = tmp?.ToString() ?? "Tmp to string is null";
```

This expression set the *oldValue* variable to `tmp.ToString()` if this is not NULL, or `tmp = "Tmp to string is null”` if is null.

References:

1. [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)
2. [This page is in Spanish but it explains it better than the official documentation.](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/operador-null-coalescing.html)

Comment: string oldValue = tmp?.ToString() ?? "Tmp to string is null";

Comment: It could be a better option in case tmp was null (I didn't test it, but it could be that it gave an error in this specific case). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast to non nullable, like this

```
    int? tmp = 0;
    
    string oldValue = tmp == null ? "" : ((int)tmp).ToString();
```

or using your syntax

```
    string oldValue;

    if (tmp is null)
        oldValue = "";
    else
        oldValue = ((int) tmp).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file explorer you should have a file with `.csproj` extension.

There you can find at row 7 the option nullable, write `disable` instead of `enable`.

Correct File:

[image: Correct File]